# How to create in app purchase in android?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play-services, google-play

I want to download and add contents and features in existing app, when In-app purchase like games contents and other multiple applications use that google play features.

I have already   follow that [Android UI: Taking a look at iosched open source app](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/01/android-ui-taking-a-look-at-iosched-open-source-app.html?utm_content=buffer79830&utm_medium=social&utm_source=facebook.com&utm_campaign=buffer)
But not solve my problem.

Note that my requirement is:

1. I don't want to add images,sounds or videos but wants to add the executable portion in my app
2. The executable portions would be the half of the app may be having activities and layouts!
3. Also how to interact with those executable portions, without installing another app of
   those portions.
4. Note that, i don't want to install app and use it using content providers or content resolvers. But wants to add those executable portions in my app without re-installation of  app or update whole app.

any helping link or tut would be highly appreciate-able. Thank you!

Comment: [Helping Link](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=How+to+create+in+app+purchase+in+android%3F&oq=How+to+create+in+app+purchase+in+android%3F&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8)